# Azure AKS: Find out why node was restarted

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

From time to time a node gets restarted in ou Azure Kubernetes service. I see that under the Activity Log of that vm (in the azure portal):

- Restart Virtual Machine, Event initiated by "ClusterServicePrincipal"

What is the best way to find out, why kubernetes restarted this node?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: You can check the node log inside.

Comment: how exactly? I see in the activity logs that the VM was restarted 6 hours ago, but when i do a kubectl describe node <node-name>, I do not see anything about this restart.

Comment: It's the system log, you can ssh into the node and see the system log.

Comment: If this is new as of today you may be affected by the outage currently impacting Azure: 9/4/2018 - 11:58 EST: "Engineers are in the process of restoring power to affected data center devices. Resources in South Central and potentially other regions may experience impact. Please refer to your portal, status.azure.com and/or Twitter for updates."